# jQuery validate showError blocks highlight

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

On my website i need to use validation in the form, however the form has tabs. When running `.validate()` I want to `highlight` the invalid input AND pop up a summary message saying that you have issues and go to the X tab to fix it. The `showErrors` seems to block the `highlight` method

Pop-up works, `highlight` doesn't. remove `showError` and `highlight` works

Here is my code:

```
$("#frmMyForm").validate({
    onclick: false,
    onkeyup:false,
    ignore: ":disabled",
   rules: {

        PasswordExpiryDays: { required: true, number: true, min: 30, max: 90 },
        PasswordStrength: { required: true, number: true, min: 10, max: 50 }

    },
    messages: {

        PasswordExpiryDays: {
            required: " This can't be left blank",
            min: "Please enter a number between 30 and 90",
            max: "Please enter a number between 30 and 90"
        },
          PasswordStrength: {
            required: " This can't be left blank",
            min: "Please enter a number between 10 and 50",
            max: "Please enter a number between 10 and 50"
        }

    },

   showErrors: function (errorMap, errorList) {
       //code for error message pop-up
    }
});
```

Comment: Quote:  *"The `showErrors` seems to block the `highlight` method"* ~ That's exactly how it's supposed to work.  `showErrors` is for creating an *alternative* to the default messages and will disable them.   However, the developer provides a method for bringing them back.  [See documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#showerrors).

Answer (score 1):

ok including

```js
this.defaultShowErrors();
```

on `showErrors` fixes the issue